# Save mail to local path using Redemption courses subject, from mail and other information to disappear

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-redemption

When ever I save a mail to a local path on the system, it breaks, meaning that subject, from mail and other information gets lost.

This started only a few weeks ago, and until then the code has been working for years.

I've tried to short down the code to include the relevant code in the question.

```
Dim oRMail As Object
Dim oExplorer As Explorer
oExplorer = m_oUtilities.OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer


oRMail = New Redemption.SafeMailItem
oRMail.Item = oExplorer.Selection;

oRMail.SaveAs(strPath, 3)
```

Have any one else had this problem? I use Outlook 365 64bit, Windows 10.

Comment: Where does the selected item come from? Is it a received or composed item? Have you tried using the Outlook object model with the [MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas) method instead? Does it work correctly?

Comment: Is this in online mode?

Answer (score 0):

Some recent changes in the MSEMS provider cause a call to `IMessage::GetProps` (which Redemption uses to retrieve multiple properties in a single call) to fail the whole call rather than return an error for a particular property in the returned array.

Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you a version with a fix.